# Fast database managment between server database and android device database

Tags: java, android, mysql, database

I want to implement a system where I have a local database in an android device, this local database will share the database to a global database were the global database will respond to the local database by adding,removing, or updating the entries of the local database by certain information (control information). The updates needs to be made very fast. 
Can anyone please share with me the most efficient and easy way to implement this system?

Thank you

Comment: I have the local database finished on android using sqlite. but I have  no idea on how to implement the server side of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a function built for it but if it needs to be fast I'm assuming you don't want to write all the scripts on server side to manage your sql statements. I'd use windows azure mobile services. have a look into it :)

Comment: I'm using android. and android requires a java operating system

Comment: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started/

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DBHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "APP_DB.db";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static String Table_CATEGORY = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [Categories] ([USERID] TEXT, [catid] TEXT, [catname] TEXT, [parentid]TEXT)";
public static String Table_ADDRESS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [Address] ([USERID] TEXT, [address_name] TEXT, [address_phone] TEXT,[address_pincode] TEXT, [address_details] TEXT, [address_city] TEXT, [address_landmark] TEXT, [address_tag] TEXT)";
private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

public DBHelper(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(Table_CATEGORY);
        db.execSQL(Table_ADDRESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Categories");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Address");

        onCreate(db);
    }
}

// ---opens the database---
public DBHelper open() throws SQLException {
    myDataBase = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// ---closes the database---
public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
}




public long insertCategories(DBCaModel categories, String userid) {
    long rowNo = 0;
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(DatabaseStaticField.KEY_User_ID, userid);
    initialValues.put(DatabaseStaticField.KEY_CATEGORY_ID,
            categories.getCatId());
    initialValues.put(DatabaseStaticField.KEY_CATEGORY_NAME,
            categories.getCat_name());
    initialValues.put(DatabaseStaticField.KEY_CATEGORY_PARENTID,
            categories.getCatParent_id());
    rowNo = myDataBase.insert(DatabaseStaticField.DATABASE_TABLE_CATEGORY,
            null, initialValues);

    return rowNo;
}

public void deleteCategories() {
    myDataBase.delete(DatabaseStaticField.DATABASE_TABLE_CATEGORY, null,
            null);
}


public List<String> getCategories(String sql, String columName) {
    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
    List<String> mVillageList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            mVillageList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columName)));
        } while (c.moveToNext());

    }
    c.close();
    return mVillageList;
}

public String getCategoriesName(String sql) {
    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
    List<String> mVillageList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            mVillageList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseStaticField.KEY_CATEGORY_NAME)));
        } while (c.moveToNext());

    }
    c.close();
    return mVillageList.get(0);
}


public ArrayList<Categories> getCategories(String sql) {
    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
    ArrayList<Categories> categoriesList = new ArrayList<Categories>();
    if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            Categories model=new Categories();
            model.setCat_id(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseStaticField.KEY_CATEGORY_ID)));
            model.setCat_name(c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(DatabaseStaticField.KEY_CATEGORY_NAME)));
            model.setParent_id(c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(DatabaseStaticField.KEY_CATEGORY_PARENTID)));
            categoriesList.add(model);
        } while (c.moveToNext());

    }
    c.close();
    return categoriesList;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BillnoxCryptography {

private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";

public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
    return toHex(result);
}

public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
    byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
    return new String(result);
}

private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) {
    seed = Arrays.copyOf(seed, 16);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(seed, ALGORITHM);
    byte[] raw = key.getEncoded();
    return raw;
}

// Since the credentials are already secured through shared prefs, we're
// using this as a lightweight solution for obfuscation. Fixing SecureRandom
// to provide cryptographically strong values is outside the scope of this
// application. See
// http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html
@SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, ALGORITHM);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, ALGORITHM);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;
}

public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
    int len = hexString.length() / 2;
    byte[] result = new byte[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16).byteValue();
    }

    return result;
}

public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
    if (buf == null) {
        return "";
    }

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2 * buf.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);
    }

    return result.toString();
}

private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";

private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b >> 4) & 0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b & 0x0f));
}
}


public class BillNoxApp extends Application {



private Activity localActivity;
public static Context mcontext;
private DBHelper db = null;
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}




@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    this.mcontext = this.getApplicationContext();
    try {
        BillNoxApp.mcontext =this;
        db = new DBHelper(this);
        db.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Exception", e + "");
    }

}
public static Context getContext() {

    return mcontext;
}
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    db.close();
    super.onTerminate();
}

public DBHelper getDatabase() {
    return db;
}


public void setLocalActivity(Activity localActivity) {
    this.localActivity = localActivity;
}

public Activity getLocalActivity() {
    return this.localActivity;
}




}
```